# How to make a shell command totally silent (preventing it to split window or to open a new frame/window etc)

Tags: latex, shell

Is it possible to run a shell command silently (in background)? When I use `async-shell-command`, emacs split the windows. I would like that an specific shell command to be totally in background (without any visual effect).

As an explicit example, I have the following code (borrowed from https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/7932). It opens the pdf version of the tex-file I working on. When running it, it splits the window, I would like to prevent it from this behavior in this particular situation.

```
 (defun my-view-pdf ()
  (interactive)
  (async-shell-command
    (concat "SumatraPDF " (file-name-base (buffer-file-name)) ".pdf")))
```

Comment: Not about the abstract question, but the specific use case: Are you using AUCTeX?  Any particular reason you're not using `TeX-view` (`C-c C-v`)?

Comment: @Dan the problem is that when I do `C-c C-v` nothing happens. I don't understand why. If you know a simple customization in the `.emacs` which makes `C-c C-v` works , I would be happy to use it. My OS is Windows and my pdf viewer is located at `C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF\sumatrapdf.exe`. In that link lawlist has provided a comprehensive link. I am only interested to make TeX-viewer works.

Comment: Not on Windows, so can't say why you're having problems.  You might try working with `TeX-view-program-list`.

Comment: This question has very good answers so I will hate for this to get closed. But this is a duplicate of this question: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/5553/115

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I run an async process in the background without popping up a buffer?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/299/how-can-i-run-an-async-process-in-the-background-without-popping-up-a-buffer)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`save-window-excursion` is a macro for running a piece of code without altering the window configuration. Something like this should work:

```
 (defun my-view-pdf ()
  (interactive)
  (save-window-excursion
   (async-shell-command
     (concat "SumatraPDF " (file-name-base (buffer-file-name)) ".pdf"))))
```

---

Note the warning in the docstring of `save-window-excursion`:

> BEWARE: Most uses of this macro introduce bugs.
> E.g. it should not be used to try and prevent some code from opening
> a new window, since that window may sometimes appear in another frame,
> in which case `save-window-excursion` cannot help.

In this case I think it should be fine, though, as it is an interactive function that doesn't really interact with any other code.

Comment: Nice macro, I confirm that your solution works.

Comment: @legoscia You were looking for `save-window-excursion`, which is nearly identical to your implementation.

Comment: @bmag I am interested to know about the difference between `save-window-excursion` and `save-window-configuration`. It seems that both work in this situation.

Comment: @Name No difference, except that `save-window-excursion` uses some macro best practices to avoid introducing variables into the environment of the body. Also, `save-window-excursion` is built-in to Emacs. I was looking for that macro, but didn't find it, so I wrote my own version. Fortunately bmag knew the real one.

Answer (score 10):

If you just would like to spawn a process in the background you don't need all the bells an whistles that shell command functions provide.

Instead, you can use the function `call-process`. For example:

```
(call-process
 "a_command"
 nil
 0                                  ; <- Discard and don't wait
 nil
 "arg1"
 "arg2")
```

Concretely, this mean that you can implement you command as:

```
(defun my-view-pdf ()
    (interactive)
    (call-process "SumatraPDF" nil 0 nil
                  (concat (file-name-base (buffer-file-name)) ".pdf")))
```

Comment: I tried to apply your suggestion for my specific example `(defun my-pdf-viewer ()
  (interactive)
   (call-process
  (async-shell-command
     (concat "SumatraPDF " (file-name-base (buffer-file-name)) ".pdf"))
nil
 0                                  ; <- Discard and don't wait
 nil
 "arg1"
 "arg2")
)`
I get the error ` Wrong type argument: stringp, comint-output-filter`. I am not sure if the syntax I used is correct.

Comment: You should drop `async-shell-command` all together. It should be something like `(defun my-pdf-viewer () (interactive) (call-process "SumatraPDF" nil 0 nil (concat (file-name-base (buffer-file-name)) ".pdf"))`.

Comment: Thank you, your solution works perfectly, there was only a missing brace, so the correct code should be : `(defun my-view-pdf () 
(interactive) 
(call-process "SumatraPDF" nil 0 nil (concat (file-name-base (buffer-file-name)) ".pdf")))
`.

Comment: @Name, thanks, I've updated the answer to include the concrete function.

Answer (score 8):

Use `display-buffer-alist` with the `display-buffer-no-window` if you're on Emacs 24.4 or later.

```
(setq display-buffer-alist '(("\\`\\*Async Shell Command\\*\\'" display-buffer-no-window)))
```

Alternatively, use [shackle](https://github.com/wasamasa/shackle):

```
(setq shackle-rules '(("*Async Shell Command*" :ignore t)))
```

Comment: Using `(setq display-buffer-alist '(("\\`\\*Async Shell Command\\*\\'" display-buffer-no-window)))` I get the error `apply: Wrong type argument: sequencep, display-buffer-no-window`.

Comment: Oh right, `display-buffer-no-window` was introduced in Emacs 24.4, so that won't work.  My package on the other hand should work on 24.3.

Comment: Backporting `display-buffer-no-window` is a third option, just insert `(defun display-buffer-no-window (_buffer alist) (when (cdr (assq 'allow-no-window alist)) 'fail))` in your Emacs configuration.

Comment: I tried to apply your last comment by putting the things all together `(defun display-buffer-no-window (_buffer alist) (when (cdr (assq 'allow-no-window alist)) 'fail))

(setq display-buffer-alist '(("\\`\\*Async Shell Command\\*\\'" display-buffer-no-window)))


 (defun my-view-pdf ()
  (interactive)
(progn
  (async-shell-command
    (concat "SumatraPDF " (file-name-base (buffer-file-name)) ".pdf"))))
`. But after executing `my-view-pdf`, emacs splits the window and `*Async Shell Command*` is shown.

Comment: I confirm that your solution perfectly works for the version 24.4 or later.

Comment: [Link to a similar QnA thread on emacs.SE](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/5554/115)